# Can reuptake absorb a selective or non-selective agonist?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

For example, a lot of antipsychotics are chemically similar to serotonin, and at least partially trigger certain types of serotonin receptors.  Is there any evidence to suggest that, because of their chemical similarity, they can be absorbed into the neuron via reuptake?  Meaning, that this agonist could be recycled and continuously partially trigger the specific serotonin receptors?

Or, possibly more likely, has there been any evidence to suggest this can happen with non-selective agonists?

Comment: that sounds extremely unlikely.  especially because low serotonin levels are unlikely to be a result of the neuron having trouble chemically synthesizing serotonin.  rather it is a result of reduced release.